# How to validate json response in bean shell and perform some action in case the response is not as expected in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want to extract the json response in jmeter and if the response is not as expected, i need to print it to a csv file.

i tried using the contains method to check if the response contains an expected keyword but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anyother way I can do this?

Sample Code here:

```
log.info(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString());

r = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode();

d = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();

if(!d.contains("valid")){

p.println(r +","+ vars.get("email") +",");

}
```

This is my json response

```
{
     "isBlueLinkServicePinValid": "valid"
}
```

I'm checking for the keyword "valid"

```
if(!d.contains("valid"))
```

But it doesn't seem to work?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is not recommended to use Beanshell for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), you should go for JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language instead. The main reason is that [Groovy has much better performance than Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) does.
2. [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) therefore you can extract  `isBlueLinkServicePinValid` attribute value in an easy way:

   ```
   String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
   log.info("Response: " + response)
   String valid = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(response).isBlueLinkServicePinValid
   log.info("Valid: " + valid);
   if (valid.equals("valid")) {
       log.info("Do something");
   }
   else {
       log.info("Do something else");  
   }
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]